# How To: Specific complex grouping query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I am not sure if this query I repeated, if so please do guide me according to the "Answered" query. And I am not sure what could be appropriate title for this query.

I have the following data in my SQL Server 2008 R2

```
|Date              |Status      |
|------------------|------------|
|29-Mar-2016 07:30 |X           |
|29-Mar-2016 07:31 |Y           |
|29-Mar-2016 07:32 |Y           |
|29-Mar-2016 07:33 |Y           |
|29-Mar-2016 07:34 |Y           |
|29-Mar-2016 07:40 |X           |
|29-Mar-2016 07:43 |Z           |
|29-Mar-2016 07:45 |Z           |
```

The result what I am expecting is as follows

```
|Start Date        | End Date         |Status     |
|------------------|------------------|-----------|
|29-Mar-2016 07:30 |29-Mar-2016 07:31 |X          |
|29-Mar-2016 07:31 |29-Mar-2016 07:34 |Y          |
|29-Mar-2016 07:40 |29-Mar-2016 07:43 |X          |
|29-Mar-2016 07:43 |29-Mar-2016 07:45 |Z          |
```

Any suggestion on the SQL queries.

Comment: It looks like `gaps-and-islands`, but the required logic is not clear. Why sometimes `end date` is taken from the same group as the `start date` and sometimes it is taken from the next group?

Comment: @VladimirBaranov The date is captured in milliseconds. The last row of the grouped data of "Y" becomes the end date and the starting of grouped data of "X" becomes the starting date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DECLARE @TEMP AS TABLE(
    [Date] DATETIME,
    [Status] VARCHAR
)

INSERT INTO @TEMP VALUES('29.03.2016 07:30','X')
INSERT INTO @TEMP VALUES('29.03.2016 07:31','Y')
INSERT INTO @TEMP VALUES('29.03.2016 07:32','Y')
INSERT INTO @TEMP VALUES('29.03.2016 07:33','Y')
INSERT INTO @TEMP VALUES('29.03.2016 07:34','Y')
INSERT INTO @TEMP VALUES('29.03.2016 07:40','X')
INSERT INTO @TEMP VALUES('29.03.2016 07:43','Z')
INSERT INTO @TEMP VALUES('29.03.2016 07:45','Z')

SELECT * FROM @TEMP

;WITH TEMP(n,d,s)
AS
(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY [Date]),[Date],[Status]
    FROM @TEMP
), StatePeriods(n,T_n,T_d,T_s,TL_n,TL_d,TL_s,TR_n,TR_d,TR_s)
AS
(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY T.d),T.n,T.d,T.s,TL.n,TL.d,TL.s,TR.n,TR.d,TR.s
    FROM TEMP AS T
    LEFT JOIN TEMP AS TR ON T.n = TR.n-1
    LEFT JOIN TEMP AS TL ON T.n-1 = TL.n
    WHERE T.s <> TR.s OR T.s <> TL.s OR TR.s IS NULL OR TL.s IS NULL
)
SELECT SP1.T_n,SP1.T_d,SP1.T_s,SP1.TL_d,SP1.TL_s,CASE WHEN SP1.T_s = SP3.T_s THEN SP3.TR_d ELSE SP3.T_d END
FROM StatePeriods AS SP1
LEFT JOIN StatePeriods AS SP2 ON SP1.n-1 = SP2.n
LEFT JOIN StatePeriods AS SP3 ON SP1.n+1 = SP3.n
WHERE NOT (SP1.T_s=SP2.T_s AND SP1.TL_s IS NOT NULL AND SP1.TR_s IS NOT NULL)
```

And you can filter first or last row

This is a very resource-intensive solution. But you can use temporary tables instead of 'WITH'

Comment: Thank you for this solution. Works like charm!! I have also added the timediff to this query. How ever I have a follow-up query on this will post it according soon.